# How to block Minecraft on YouTube on Android phone?

Tags: applications, youtube

I have a child who is too young to watch computer games on youtube.

How can I block Minecraft on youtube search and videos on my phone? (Android)
I tried **Youtube Kids** app. I blocked several videos, but I can still find other videos typing "Minecraft". Is it possible to block the search by whole words?

Also: Is it possible to block the search for "Minecraft" on the Google bar?
Or Is there a web browser that allows blocking by keywords?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with [Google Family Link](https://families.google.com/familylink/).

You install Family Link on your device (or some device that is managed by an adult) and simply configure the content you will allow your child to see and use.  You can configure everything from Filters on Google Chrome/Search to location and account information.

I'm not sure Google Family Link has everything you describe exactly out of the box, but with some adjustments I'm sure you can manage.  For example, instead of filtering out what you don't want to see, you might instead have to specify what you do want to see - i.e., a whitelist approach instead of a blacklist approach.

Here is the link to the Google Play app Family Link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.kids.familylink&hl=en_US